# С чего начать написание своей стандартной библиотеки C?

Tags: linux, libc

С чего начать при написании своей стандартной библиотеки C (по типу glibc, bionic, BSD libc)? Хоть я и знаю C и ассемблер на базовом уровне, но не понимаю до конца, что и как писать. Плюс не совсем понимаю, как работает линкер (имею в виду `/system/bin/linker` в Android или `/lib/ld.so` в Linux или BSD).

Казалось бы, почему бы не использовать существующие варианты stdlib c - musl, bionic, glibc, uclibc, dietlibc, ну или на худой конец - выдернуть BSD libc? Ну, по порядку:

glibc - мне нужна hardened библиотека. И да, опций компилятора в духе `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=3` мне недостаточно.

musl - та же проблема, что и с glibc.

bionic - ну, есть более hardened варианты (вариант самого бионика от Copperhead OS, OpenBSD libc), плюс есть проблема. bionic сильно заточен под Android. Т е надо будет убирать Android-специфичные части или переписывать их, оставляя нужный мне hardening.

dietlibc - не умеет в динамическую линковку, плюс нету части стандартных функций C. Ну и конечно, никакого харденинга.

uclibc и klibc - те же проблемы, что с glibc, плюс нету части стандартных функций.

BSD libc - придётся убирать BSD специфичные части и добавлять Linux-специфичные (особенно это касается OpenBSD libc). В остальном - неплохой вариант, hardening там хороший.

Поэтому у меня есть мысль написать свою реализацию `libc.so`. Но как это сделать?

Comment: Мне самому интересно, кто-нибудь тут сможет вам **конкретно** помочь?  (Судя по вашему анализу библиотек вы уже глубоко изучили эту тему. Что же касается меня, то из-за глубокого отвращения ко всяким ограничениям из соображений security (я же не ошибаюсь, **hardening** именно из этой области?) заниматься этим вопросом не хочется)

Comment: в случае с libc hardening заключается обычно в модификации памяте-опасных функций (malloc/calloc/realloc, семейство printf, string.h функции), для предотвращения ряда атак и эксплойтов (use-after-free, ROP, выход за пределы массива, т д). Можете почитать как это устроено в OpenBSD [libc]

Comment: Подозреваю, "убирать Android-специфичные части" будет всё-таки проще чем писать всё с нуля?

Comment: К сожалению, я не из тех, кто хорошо умеет копаться в **чужом** коде...